# Random Occurrences of Blank Contribution Thank You Pages

Tags: civicontribute

This is strange. Some donors are donating successfully but getting a blank thank you page. They get an email confirming their donation, but nothing on screen. D7 CiviCRM 5.31, Omnipay Cybersource

I can't seem to find any issues in the log either.

The URL at the blank screen is `/civicrm/payment/ipn/1`

When it works correctly, the thank you screen has a url of  `civicrm/contribute/transact?_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=**********************`

Any ideas?

Comment: any chance some folk get to the page via http and others via https. or some with www and some without?

Comment: This is what one user provided as a URL for the blank page. /civicrm/payment/ipn/1

Comment: but do you get to the same path when you succeed? and what is the rest of the path as that is my wild guess as to what might be happening?

Comment: Hi again, 
civicrm/contribute/transact?_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=**********************
Is what is supposed to happen - and does happen most of the time. *** is the actual key just in case that was not clear.

Comment: not sure i can be helpful. i asked about whether some might be going via http v https or www v no www but you haven't commented on that

Comment: it is https and there is no www.

Comment: Answer below, thanks @petednz-fuzion for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to Drupal 7 (possibly wordpress), PHP prior to 7.3 and Chrome 80+

To fix, upgrade to PHP 7.3 and add the following text somewhere in your drupal 7 settings.php file.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
```

or you can style it like we did so you remember why you added this.

```
/**
 * Fix for Chrome Cookies Issue - See:
 * https://www.zoocha.com/news/how-fix-chrome-80-cookies-issue-drupal & 
 * https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2059
*/
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
```

Clear CiviCRM and Drupal caches.
Clear browser cookies and cache.

(Unfortunately for your returning users, unless you have them clear their browser cache/cookies, they might experience the blank screen again.)

If you do not want to upgrade to PHP7.3 the zoocha article explains how to fix in previous versions.